# Convert Ruby code to string

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting

I am refactoring some code that I did not write, and I found a line that looks like this (it is much longer, i used just a little bit for this example):

```
system("rubyw -e \"require 'win32ole'; @autoit=WIN32OLE.new('AutoItX3.Control');")
```

To increase readability, I refactored it to

```
do_something =
  "rubyw -e \"
    require 'win32ole'
    @autoit=WIN32OLE.new('AutoItX3.Control')"
system do_something
```

Then I wanted to make some changes, but since the code I am working on is in a string, I lose syntax highlighting, parenthesis matching and all that good stuff.

Is there an easy way to write some code outside of the string and then convert it to string?

I have searched the web and stackoverflow, but could not find the answer.

For more information, take a look at original code at [bret/watir](http://github.com/bret/watir/blob/d6c28c90de2025f3889856789dfde1049bd1fa00/watir/lib/watir/input_elements.rb) (Watir::FileField#set, line 445), and my fork at [zeljkofilipin/watir](http://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watir/blob/261bc2c519640a601c932482aa115ef59fdb2955/watir/lib/watir/input_elements.rb) (lines 447-459).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
do_something = <<SOMETHING
  rubyw -e 
  require 'win32ole'
  @autoit=WIN32OLE.new('AutoItX3.Control')
SOMETHING
```

Apparently it's a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heredoc)! You can find another example [here(doc)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)#Strings).

That's not to say that the command won't freak out about having line breaks in there. However you could likely run it by `system do_something.split(/\r\n/).join('')` or something like that.

Comment: It's called a "here document", or "heredoc" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

Comment: vim highlights heredocs as strings. Also, if you want a multiline string without escaping quotes, %{} is a more rubyish way to do it

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could just put the code into an external file and load that.

Alternatively, if I remember correctly, Ruby files may contain `DATA` sections:

```
# Sample ruby file:

puts DATA.readline()

__END__
foo bar
```

This should print "`foo bar`". You could put your code in the data segment. With any luck, your editor will still provide syntax highlighting for the `DATA` segment.

Comment: Is it just me, or is something wrong with your example?

    > puts DATA
      NameError: uninitialized constant DATA
      from (irb):1

Comment: It works for me … no error there. I've updated the source code though, to create the right output.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby2ruby sounds kind of like what you're asking.

http://seattlerb.rubyforge.org/ruby2ruby/